# Fail to set figure gid in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I want to set figure gid in matplotlib and save it into svg file. I found that I can get correct result by calling `get_gid()` but fail to get in svg file.

The testing code I use is like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FIGURE_ID = "the_figure"
FIGURE_PATCH_ID = "the_figure_patch"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 9))
fig.clf()
fig.set_gid(FIGURE_ID)
fig.patch.set_gid(FIGURE_PATCH_ID)

print(fig.get_gid())
print(fig.patch.get_gid())

fig.savefig('id_test.svg', format='svg')
```

And the output from console is:

```sh
the_figure
the_figure_patch
```

But when I open the svg file, it comes like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/) -->
<svg height="648pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1080 648" width="1080pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
*{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;}
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="figure_1">
  <g id="the_figure_patch">
   <path d="M 0 648 
L 1080 648 
L 1080 0 
L 0 0 
z
" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Which proves that **the patch gid has been changed**, but **the figure gid remains**. Please help me to figure out my naive problem! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The reason is that in [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a43e85cc89d9dc7c4f4977387540c91ca10b097/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L1727) no gid is passed. If it was `renderer.open_group('figure', gid=self.get_gid())`, it would probably work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works. But I think it seems to have some resolutions by just modifying my code, without changing files in matplotlib, since it's not a rare need.

Comment: I filed a fix in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/15087

Comment: Yes, I saw it. In fact, when I want to set objects which have a attribute `get_children()` function, it will cause the same problem, (axes, axis, legend, tick included in my test). I fixed it in my local machine with the same way, by modifying these: [axes](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a43e85cc89d9dc7c4f4977387540c91ca10b097/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2563), [tick](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a43e85cc89d9dc7c4f4977387540c91ca10b097/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L294)

Comment: (sorry the previous comment is too long).  and [axis](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a43e85cc89d9dc7c4f4977387540c91ca10b097/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L1250), [legend](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9a43e85cc89d9dc7c4f4977387540c91ca10b097/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L636)